# Property data types while using Realm.io and RestKit together

Tags: ios, swift, restkit, restkit-0.20, realm

I am trying to use RestKit with Realm.io and am having an issue with property data types.  I have a property that is an integer.  RestKit seems to only want to map to a `NSNumber` type (https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping), while a realm object only allows properties that are primitives (`Int`, `Float`, `Double`, etc (http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.87.4/#property-types)).

I've seen other indications that these two frameworks can be used together ([Can i use RestKit and Realm.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252759/can-i-use-restkit-and-realm-io)), but I'm not sure how to get around this issue.

For example, if I use an `NSNumber` data type, the `RLMObject` will fail and give the error

```
'RLMException', reason: ''NSNumber' is not supported as an RLMObject property...'
```

But if I use a primitive data type to make realm happy I get a `'key value coding-compliant'` error from RestKit.

It's the worst.

I've tried adding a RestKit value transformer to the property, thinking that maybe I would be able to toggle back and forth between data types whenever a rest call needed to be made. But that strategy is on it's way to being a stackoverflow question of its own.

It's actually the worst.

Has anybody done this?  Am I onto something with the value transformer?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you please post your RLMObject model? I'm not having any issues with RestKit and Realm with primitive properties. Though I'm in objc and I just now saw you're having this issue in Swift. I'll try that next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not having any issues getting RestKit to work with primitive number types in Swift. Here's my code:

```
class TwitterError: RLMObject {
    dynamic var message = ""
    dynamic var code = 0

    override var description: String { return "Error \(code): \(message)" }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let mapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: TwitterError.self)
        mapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(["message": "message", "code": "code"])
        let responseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: mapping, pathPattern: nil, keyPath: "errors", statusCodes: nil)
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let operation = RKObjectRequestOperation(request: request, responseDescriptors: [responseDescriptor])
        operation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess(nil, failure: nil)
        operation.start()
    }
}
```

which outputs a description of `"Error 92: SSL is required"`, which means that both code (`Int`) and message (`String`) are being parsed properly.

Comment: Thanks @jpsim - do you know what data type this ends up being once it's instantiated?  Because I get an error if I try to explicitly declare the type but the code you have seems to work for me as well.  Thanks again.

Comment: The code property is an `Int` and this still works when defining the property as `dynamic var code: Int = 0`